# Is there a way to inadvertently stop the threads of an Executor?

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried crashing the Thread of a fixed thread pool of a standard `ExecutorService` with this horrible code, in order to test its resilience against exceptions and errors happening inside the tasks passed to the `ExecutorService`:

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    executorService.execute(() -> {
        throw new RuntimeException("Trying to kill the thread");
    });
    Thread.sleep(100);
    executorService.execute(() -> {
        System.out.println("still executing");
    });
```

but the second task prints `still executing` so I think the exception is being caught or the `Thread` instance is restarted anyway.
What is happening? Can I trust that no matter what happens inside a task (less than `System.exit()`) other submitted tasks will continue to be executed by the pool?

Comment: It's right there in the API docs which you should probably read. "If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks. The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown."

Comment: It's not horrible code, it's a _learning test_.  As shown, it's only a manual test, but you could automate it, and make it part of  the unit-test suite for some application in order to document that the application depends on that behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your executor service uses a thread pool. If a thread is killed, one another will be instantiated to execute next task.

Your call `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);` set a limit on number of active threads only.

In order to stop executor service, you must call:

```
executorService.shutdown();
```

Comment: or `executorService.shutDownNow()`.